# how to regex contains character and numbers and long

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am new to regex, and I'm looking to create the expression for 
"return '521868ad-0baf-4619-8522-99366c2e5211';"
it is in this below code. I use Jmeter for test performance This below code is response data. please check attach image.[This is response data code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jvyJ.png)
[This is expression of me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUdNf.png)
I try to use '(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$/[36])', but it do not work. Please, help me.

```
 $if (!count) {
            sessionStorage.setItem(key, 0);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    },
    isFirstTimeLoggedIn: function() {
        var loginTime = parseInt("0");
        return loginTime == 1;
    }
};
  //disable back button
   var securityType ='SM';//SM --> send OTP,(opt input) to your phone or TK --> 
  No OTP ID, no Button Resend OTP (token input)
  var commonCertCode ='011487793';
  var timeCreateToken ='1531820782309';
  var isPwdStrong ='N';
  var isPwdPopupShow = true;
  var tokenService = {
    get : function() {
        var tokenNoStorage = sessionStorage.getItem("msb.tokenNo");
        if (tokenNoStorage &&  typeof   tokenNoStorage ==   "string") {
            var timeCreate = sessionStorage.getItem("msb.timeCreateToken");
            console.log('1531820782309');
            if (timeCreate != null && timeCreate > '1531820782309') {
                return tokenNoStorage;
            }
        } else {
            return '521868ad-0baf-4619-8522-99366c2e5211';
        }
    },
    set : function(tokenNumber, time) {
        if (tokenNumber &&  typeof  tokenNumber ==  "string") {
            sessionStorage.setItem("msb.tokenNo", tokenNumber);
            sessionStorage.setItem("msb.timeCreateToken", time);
            tokenNo = tokenNumber;
        }
    },
    clear : function() {
        sessionStorage.removeItem("msb.tokenNo");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("msb.timeCreateToken");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple regular expression using left and right boundaries

```
return '(.+?)';
```

and use $1$ as template

or else you can use  `return '([a-zA-Z0-9-]{36})';` and use $1$ as tempalte, which extracts the string of length 36

For more information on JMeter regular expression extration please follow [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)

you can test your regular expressions [here](https://regex101.com/) ..

Please let  me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you very much .
I use `return '([a-zA-Z0-9-]{36})';` and it was done.